# Facebook Audience Network missing file 'fb_an_config.plist'

Tags: ios, admob, facebook-audience-network

I am implementing Facebook Audience Network for IOS through Admob Mediation.

I have installed the following POD files:

- pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
- pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
- pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
- pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
- pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'

I have added the libAdapterFacebook.a (Facebook Adapter for Admob Mediation)

When I run the app I got the following log:

> [FBAudienceNetworkLog/FBAdConfigManager:78 ] Failed to load local configuration: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “fb_an_config.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C399A7FE-03B2-49EC-89C6-BCC73EBF0076/Library/Caches/fb_an_config.plist, NSUnderlyingError=0x14de133d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

I did not find in any documentation the need to create this file: **fb_an_config.plist**

Somebody can help me on that?

Comment: Do you have any `Watch Kit Extension` or `Today Extension` target in your app?

Comment: Yes. I do. @atulkhatri

Comment: I think Audience network is being initialized for these extensions as well. It's showing error because it can't find the plist over there. Still to check if the latest SDK fixes this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has fixed this issue and it will be updated in the v4.10.1 of iOS SDK...
check out [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1691622177774648/)

Comment: This is strange because I'm getting the exact same error 5 years later when trying to run Facebook Audience Network ads through IronSource mediation. And I'm on version 8.1.1. [FBAudienceNetworkLog/FBAdConfigManager:377 thread:1 <debug>] Failed to load local configuration: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “fb_an_config.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."